# Can't Save Class (batch or future jobs pending or in progress)

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, scheduled-job, asyncapexjob

I have a problem saving one of my classes into server. The error that I get is:

> Error: Compile Error: This Apex class has batch or future jobs pending or in progress at line -1 column -1

I have tried everything mentioned in **[this article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004423&language=en_US&type=1)** and none worked. (I even logged a case with Salesforce and they said we don't support devs, ask your question online).

To be more specific, I tried the following scripts:

```
List<CronTrigger> listCronTrigger = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, EndTime, NextFireTime, OwnerId,
        PreviousFireTime, StartTime, State, TimesTriggered, TimeZoneSidKey FROM CronTrigger 
        WHERE State = 'Waiting' or State = 'Running'];

If (listCronTrigger.size() > 0) {
    for (Integer i = 0; i < listCronTrigger.size(); i++) { 
        System.abortJob(listCronTrigger[i].Id);
    }
}
```

also I tried running above script without the 'WHERE' condition to basically abort all the jobs. After running these scripts **I don't see any scheduled jobs in my org**:

[image: All Scheduled Jobs (empty)]

Then I tried saving to server using IlluminatedCloud on IntelliJ, Mavens Mate on Atom and still I get the same error. Then I tried saving to server using developer console on my org, same error. Then I tried directly modifying it in **Setup > Apex Classes > myClass.cls** and still get the same error:

[image: Apex Class save error]

**Update:**
The following setting in **Setup > Deployment Settings** is enabled in my org:

> Allow deployments of components when corresponding Apex jobs are
>   pending or in progress

Note that although I don't see any scheduled jobs in my org, I figured that there are bunch of old queued **apex jobs**:

[image: Apex Jobs (Queued)]

I searched for solutions to kill these jobs, the only thing I found was this script:

```
for (AsyncApexJob aJob : [SELECT Id, Status, JobItemsProcessed, TotalJobItems, NumberOfErrors FROM AsyncApexJob Where Status = 'Queued']) {
    system.abortJob(aJob.Id);
}
```

But noticed that this script is supported up to version 39!

When I logged this case with Salesforce, I got this:

[image: Support response]

Comment: I've [moved this discussion to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68079/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-ashkanent).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a hack to work around the issue and save my class. In short:

> Delete that class from your org and then save it back to server using
>   your IDE.

More Details/Explanations:
Just to recap: there was a pending Apex job with no parent CronTrigger, so I couldn't delete it using `System.abortJob()`. This is a Salesforce bug that happens when your scheduled job is delayed so much that it goes past its own execution time and then it remains there forever! If it's not a dev org, SF will remove those jobs for you manually, if not, based on above research nothing basically works. Deleting the class will get rid of these jobs.